# ContentEditable Placeholder Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I followed a SO question on how to create a placeholder for div[contenteditable].

My code looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/sdxjgkzm/

```
$('div[data-placeholder]').on 'keydown input', ->
if (this.textContent)
  this.dataset.divPlaceholderContent = 'true'
else
  delete(this.dataset.divPlaceholderContent)
```

Unfortunately, the problem is that as you can see the standard input's placeholder stays until you begin typing, while the contenteditable's goes away as soon as you click inside.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your html a bit then use the below css:use `placeholder` instead of `data-placeholder` i.e. without data attribute.

```css
input,div {
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="test"/>
<div contenteditable='true' placeholder="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, CSS only :)

[Placeholder support for contentEditable elements, without JavaScript](http://codepen.io/flesler/pen/AEIFc)

Updated Fiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/d5ep3eLw/1/)

All you need is to add the following CSS:

```css
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block; /* For Firefox */
}
/* General Styling for Demo only */
div[contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px dashed #AAA;
  width: 290px;
  padding: 5px;
}
pre {
  background: #EEE;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 290px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Placeholder support for contentEditable elements,<br>without JavaScript!</h3> 

<h5>Demo:</h5>
<div contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter text here..."></div>

<p>All you need is to add the following CSS:</p>
<pre>
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block; /* For Firefox */
}
</pre>

<h5>Notes</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Can add a different style than actual text like opacity, italic, etc</li>
  <li>If your html needs to be 100% compliant, you can replace "placeholder" for "data-placeholder" on both files</li>
  <li>Chrome will add &lt;br />'s inside contentEditable elements in some cases, breaking the :empty check. Can be fixed with a bit of JavaScript.</li>
</ul>

<i>By Ariel Flesler</i>
```

Comment: @infinity Sorry, I linked you to the wrong Fiddle. Please see the new one. http://jsfiddle.net/d5ep3eLw/1/